# Is it possible to disable Spring Boot's autoconfigurations via profile?

Tags: spring-boot

I am researching how to modify our Spring Boot-based services so that they can run both on-premises and on AWS.  We already know that we can push our Docker containers anywhere we want and run things that way.  Ideally, what I'm looking for is the ability to take advantage of the available AWS features, when available.  For example, on-premises we use RabbitMQ for messaging.  If deployed on AWS, we want to use SQS instead.  I already know know how to conditionally enable/disable beans via the profile so we can dynamically swap out the messaging gateway bean simple enough.  The challenge comes with the RabbitMQ autoconfiguration.  When running in AWS, I need all the bits that come along with `spring-boot-starter-amqp` to go dormant and not complain that a RabbitMQ instance cannot be found.  Is this possible to do or am I doomed to having two separate builds targeted to particular environments?  I'm okay with having a slightly fatter JAR file in exchange for a simpler build.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this by adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)` to the AWS specific configuration profile.

Answer (score 2):

I disabled it using properties:

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration

Source:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.auto-configuration.disabling-specific

Answer (score 1):

I was able to disable RabbitMQ on startup with:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)
```